# Left Join not showing non match record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this simple mysql query with join

```
Select

sp.PTPK, sp.EmployeeNamePK, sp.Half, sp.TaskPK, sp.TaskAssignCompletionId, sp.SwitchDate, sp.SpendDays, /*switch_person Table*/

pro.Name as ProjectName, pro.TeamLead /*Project Table*/

From switch_person sp


LEFT JOIN projects pro
ON pro.PK = sp.PTPK

Where sp.SwitchDate = '2019-03-01'
AND sp.Half =1
```

It is working correctly with one issue is that `project` unmatched record are not showing. I mean there are some non match records (projects name) which I am not getting from the project table. I know that it should be display as I am using `left join`.

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: It's most likely your `where` filter. Please check that the rows that you want to be displayed also match your `where` filter, because it will always be applied (with inner join, left join, etc.).

Comment: @EzLo Yeah seems this is the problem.

Comment: If the item is in the projects table, you are joining the wrong way round

Comment: which item in project table?

Comment: Do you mean _RIGHT JOIN_ since you want all rows from projects table?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Are you indicating this question is resolved then based on EzLo's comment?

Comment: Most probably on the date of '2019-03-01' there are no non-matching data that was 'half=1'.

Comment: Half=1 is in switch_person table while i am talking about project table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
SELECT sp.PTPK
     , sp.EmployeeNamePK
     , sp.Half
     , sp.TaskPK
     , sp.TaskAssignCompletionId
     , sp.SwitchDate
     , sp.SpendDays
     , pro.Name ProjectName
     , pro.TeamLead 
  FROM projects pro
  LEFT 
  JOIN switch_person sp
    ON pro.PK = sp.PTPK
   AND sp.SwitchDate = '2019-03-01'
   AND sp.Half = 1
```

...?

Comment: The query is extreemly inefficnet took 26 seconds to execute and missing employee name.

Comment: You're welcome; I think it selects the same columns as the original query. As to efficiency, that would be a function of indexes, but you can see why I might be disinclined to help further.

Comment: efficiency is the concern, i can use this query as it will require execution frequently .  A dashboard is developed using this.

Answer (score 0):

Updated after you last commment.

If indeed you want to always display the project data, I think you would probably be better served with a left join. Besides that, if the problem is performance, I suggest you:

1. Add an index to your switch_person table
2. Create a Stored procedure (SP) for your query

Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX mydataindex ON switch_person(PTPK, SwitchDate, Half);

CREATE
    PROCEDURE getmydata (IN filterdate date, IN half INT)
SELECT sp.PTPK
     , sp.EmployeeNamePK
     , sp.Half
     , sp.TaskPK
     , sp.TaskAssignCompletionId
     , sp.SwitchDate
     , sp.SpendDays
     , pro.Name ProjectName
     , pro.TeamLead 
  FROM projects pro
  LEFT 
  JOIN switch_person sp
    ON pro.PK = sp.PTPK
   AND sp.SwitchDate = filterdate
   AND sp.Half = half
ORDER BY 
   pro.Name;
```

Then, all you have to do is call that SP like this:

```
CALL getmydata ('2019-03-01', 1);
```

updated full code [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n57oVK8eK5xyWuJvapirYi/3)

Comment: It is helpful but the issue is that it taking 49 seconds